# Ошибка подключения к бд postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Пытаюсь подключиться к бд, но возникает ошибка следующего плана:

> Unable to connect to server: а тут пустое значение почему-то...

С чем это может быть связано?

Порт 5432,остальные данные тоже ввёл...

Comment: добавьте фрагмент кода, и уточните у вас posygresql или mysql/mariadb.

Comment: @nexoma у меня mysql/mariadb вроде.У меня xampp

Comment: Ошибка теперь другая : Unable to connect to server:

Comment: Я изменил порт на 5432,ввёл остальные данные и такая ошибка возникла

Comment: Вопрос поменял)

Comment: если mariadb, то порт 3306. фрагмент кода с коннектом сделайте. посмотрите config xampp, там может порт у вас 3307, всё может быть.

Comment: запустите nmap localhost, вы увидите открытые порты, должен обозначиться 3306 mysql

Comment: и изучать статьи по установке https://www.faqforge.com/linux/distributions/ubuntu/how-to-install-xampp-apache-mariadb-php-and-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu/  

вам следует найти свою ошибку при инсталляции, это и порты базы, и создание пользователя с требуемыми привилегиями и сетевые настройки...